# Statistics with elasticsearch suggest api

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to use the suggest-api in elasticsearch. And i would like to get total hits, as you get when you are doing a regular query.

As it is now, if i ask this of elasticsearch

```
/_suggest
{
 "name_suggest": {
  "text": "derp",
  "completion": {
   "size": 10,
   "field": "name.sugest"
  }
 }
}
```

I get 10 answers, but no information on how many other matches there is.

So the question is, is there a way yo get hold of this information, using the suggest feature? for example using facets? (i  have tried but not got anything working)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your 10 answers and build aggregation query like this:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "answer1 OR answer2 OR ...",
      "fields" : [ "name.sugest" ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "name_sugest" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "name.sugest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```